# Variable into MySQL statement is not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that lists 14 dates from a set date (2 week pay period):

```
$punchCard = array();    
Array(
        [1] => Array(
                [showDate] => 2012-12-04
                [codeDate] => 20121204)
        [2] => Array(
                [showDate] => 2012-12-05
                [codeDate] => 20121205)
    .........................................
        [12] => Array(
                [showDate] => 2012-12-15
                [codeDate] => 20121215)
        [13] => Array(
                [showDate] => 2012-12-16
                [codeDate] => 20121216)
        [14] => Array(
                [showDate] => 2012-12-17
                [codeDate] => 20121217)
    )
```

I want to loop through it and return some data from a database:

```
    foreach($punchCard as $date){
        $sql = "
              SELECT date, time 
              FROM `timeclock` 
              WHERE `employee`=" . $_SESSION['id'] . " 
              AND `date`=" . (int)$date['codeDate'] . " 
              ORDER BY `time` ASC ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $timecard = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $timecard[] = $row;
        }   
    }
```

Thats not working but:

```
$sql = "
     SELECT date, time 
     FROM `timeclock` 
     WHERE `employee`=" . $_SESSION['id'] . " 
     AND `date`=20121204 
     ORDER BY `time` ASC ";
```

somehow `(int)$date['codeDate']` is not working but I can't wrap my head around it and it's probably simple...

taylorjes

Comment: What kind of date field uses an integer? Why don't you try `echo $sql;` to see what it looks like?

Comment: `$punchCard[0]['codeDate'] = date("Ymd", strtotime("+0 day", $start));`

Comment: $sql looks identical but no array

Comment: What is your `date` data type in your table? Also, add `or die(mysql_error());` after your `mysql_query`.

Comment: `date` is `int(8)` and no errors with `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL statment was correct. The Array was not:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){//show last punch
        $timecard[]['time'] = $row['time'];
    }
```

fixed

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL has an error. `date` and `time` after `SELECT` should be quoted like this because they are function names:

```
$sql = "
 SELECT `date`, `time` 
 FROM `timeclock` 
 WHERE `employee`=" . $_SESSION['id'] . " 
 AND `date`=20121204 
 ORDER BY `time` ASC ";
```

Comment: that did give me any different results... I'm trying to fix this:
`
AND `date`='" . (int)$date['codeDate'] . "'